# How to blend multiple images in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have group of images and associated weights with it. I want to blend them together. I know there is a blend command in OpenCV to blend two images. But how do I blend multiple images together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about simple matrix operations, like the following?

```
blendedImage = weight_1 * image_1 + weight_2 * image_2 + ... + weight_n * image_n
```

Comment: Actually I tried that but it doesn't work. Later I realised that the problem was that I hadn't initialised blendedImage size and type to image size and type. Its working now.

Answer (score 5):

The blending can be done using the below code(This is in Java using OpenCV):

```
//Create a black-colored image
Mat mergedImage = new Mat(inputImageSize, inputImageType, new Scalar(0));
//Add each image from a vector<Mat> inputImages with weight 1.0/n where n is number of images to merge
for (Mat mat : inputImages) {
    Core.addWeighted(mergedImage, 1, mat, 1.0/n, 0, mergedImage);
}
```

**Edit**:- The above code suffers from rounding error. If inputImageType is an integer type, division by `1/n` will cause this issue. Thus, above code should be used only for floating matrices.

Comment: But this won't result in the correct blended image, or does it?
As the weight first images will be reduced multiple times or not?

Comment: @StefanReinhardt - Hi, please give me a day. I will look into this once out of office, but there is a good chance you are correct. As you suspect, I think the images that are added first are reduced by 1/(1+(1/n)) an extra number of times. Ignore this answer for now and my sincere apologies.

Comment: @StefanReinhardt: Safe, Safe, I'm Safe. There is no division performed -
 http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d0/d86/tutorial_py_image_arithmetics.html. :D

Comment: I am not sure, in a first place there is no division performed but as you use the results as the new input it will be wheighted once again.
At least in my tests it was the case.
But as you can multiply the input images with a scalar there is an easy fix to this. Just don't use addWeighted but perform the operation directly with    mergedImage += 1/n *mat

Comment: @StefanReinhardt: Yep, the results will be weighted again but with weight 1. This is what is actually happening here(read order:- inner most parentheses to outer and then outermost):- ( ( (1*0 + a1/n) * 1.0 + a2/n)*1.0 + a3/n) ... = a1/n + a2/n + a3/n + ... . So, the code may be different, but the logic is same. But since you have tested this and found to differ, I will work on this once out of office. But according to opencv docs, there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Ah sorry of course you are right i missed the first wheighting factor is actually one. In my code it was (n-1)/n. Sorry once again to bother you.
Now the results are the same in both cases...

Comment: No worries. I do admit it is kind of peculiar way of averaging the images :). Anyways, Happy image processing, keep on coding.

Comment: @StefanReinhardt: Hi, I recently noticed a bug. There is rounding error if original image is not float type. Will do test to confirm if this is an error & revise the answer in a day. Thought it is appropriate to let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Here is Python code to blend multiple images in a list. I used the basic formulation from Dennis' answer.

First, let's get three images.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

dim = (425, 425)

apple = mpimg.imread('apple.jpg')
apple = cv2.resize(apple, dim)

banana = mpimg.imread('banana.jpg')
banana = cv2.resize(banana, dim)

orange = mpimg.imread('orange.jpg')
orange = cv2.resize(orange, dim)

_ = plt.imshow(apple)
_ = plt.show()

_ = plt.imshow(banana)
_ = plt.show()

_ = plt.imshow(orange)
_ = plt.show()
```

Here are the images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now let's blend them together equally. Since there are three images, the fraction of each image's contribution to the final output is 0.333.

```py
def blend(list_images): # Blend images equally.

    equal_fraction = 1.0 / (len(list_images))

    output = np.zeros_like(list_images[0])

    for img in list_images:
        output = output + img * equal_fraction

    output = output.astype(np.uint8)
    return output

list_images = [apple, banana, orange]
output = blend(list_images)

_ = plt.imshow(output)
```

And here is the result:

[image]